# Xcode: How do I make a map that can show nearby locations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm in the process of making an iPhone App that can show nearby stores (the stores are a danish grocerychain of stores). In the app. I want to switch to a view where the standard iphone map is shown and I know how to make that and a pointer of my location.

Now i have a list of all the addresses of the stores. But i don't know how to make the map automatically show for example 4 or 5 of the nearest stores of my current location.

Also I would really like that when the map launches it doesn't show the entire world but it automatically zooms in on my current location in a decent way :)

I hope someone will help. I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not as simple as flipping a switch, but it can certainly be done:

1. Fetch the list of nearby store locations based on the current location of the device. Use [Core Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get the current device location and then fetch the nearby stores from either a file within the app bundle or from somewhere on the web
2. Display the stores on a map provided by [MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html) using annotations. To make sure only a relevant part of the map is show use the setRegion:animated: method of [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Comment: thanks allot :).... you wouldn't happen to have some sort of code example? because i'm kind of new to iphone programming, so I still have allot to learn :)

Comment: Check out this example code from Apple on how to use MapKit, it gives you a pretty good start: http://bit.ly/dFOYDk There are also plenty of results for a Google search with "MapKit example" :)

Comment: okay thank you very much :)... I think I got it know.... I really appreciate your help :)